# limit as supremum S

Tags: real-analysis

S is a bounded nonempty subset of the set of Real Numbers such that the sup S is not in S. Prove there is a sequence Sn of points in S such that lim Sn = sup S.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of $\sup S$, we know that $\sup S-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $S$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there must be an $s_n\in S$, such that $s_n\geq \sup S -\frac{1}{n}$.

Now try to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = \sup S$.

Comment: Can you please explain where the (1/n) comes from?

Comment: @Kar $\frac{1}{n}$ can be substituted for any strictly positive sequence converging to zero.